# Tilt iPhone to Change UIImage (Accelerometer)

Tags: iphone, swift, uiimage, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm trying to switch between 2 UIImages using the `CoreMotion` (Accelerometer) in Swift.

I've implemented a smooth fade transition effect between the two images already and I'm currently using a Button to instantiate this effect. Would like to replace this with the accelerometer, so you can control how the effect is handled.

```
    @IBAction func TapToFade(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let image1:UIImage = UIImage(named: "ImageA")!;
        let image2:UIImage = UIImage(named: "ImageB")!;
        let crossFade:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents");
        crossFade.duration = 3.0;
        crossFade.beginTime = 0.0;
        crossFade.fromValue = image1.cgImage;
        crossFade.toValue = image2.cgImage;
        imageView.layer.add(crossFade, forKey:"animateContents");

        if crossFade.beginTime < 5.0 {
            imageView.image = image2;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your device **Portrait Orientation Lock** set to be **off** in **Control Center** and try below code.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications() 
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.detectMotion),name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
 }


 func detectMotion(){
    let device = UIDevice.current
    switch device.orientation{
    case .portrait:

        let crossFade:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents");
        crossFade.duration = 3.0;
        crossFade.beginTime = 0.0;
        crossFade.fromValue = UIImage(named: "ImageB.jpg")?.cgImage
        crossFade.toValue = UIImage(named: "ImageA.jpg")?.cgImage
        imageView.layer.add(crossFade, forKey:"animateContents");

        if crossFade.beginTime < 5.0 {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImageA.jpg")
        }

    case .faceUp:

        let crossFade:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "contents");
        crossFade.duration = 3.0;
        crossFade.beginTime = 0.0;
        crossFade.fromValue = UIImage(named: "ImageA.jpg")?.cgImage
        crossFade.toValue = UIImage(named: "ImageB.jpg")?.cgImage
        imageView.layer.add(crossFade, forKey:"animateContents");

        if crossFade.beginTime < 5.0 {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImageB.jpg")
        }

    default:
        print("unknown")

    }
}
```